# How to track UICollectionViewCell inside UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Hi i was trying to track displacement for X in UICollectionView when scrolling, i tried using reactive cocoa with this code:

```
[RACObserve(self, bounds) subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    CGRect rect = [x CGRectValue];
    NSLog(@"Location: %f", rect.origin.x);
}];
```

but this is not enough cause this only track position when cell appear and this value is 0 every time.

what's the best approach to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the scrollView delegates methods, it's the easy way. Remember that a collectionView is a scrollView also.

Comment: using this method -(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView  u can track

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be using the wrong approach here. The usage paradigm for `UICollectionView`/`UICollectionViewCell`s is intended to be undesignated from my understanding.

It's quite like `UITableView` in that regard. You only want to create 'just enough' cells for the view and reuse them.

As I'm sure you are aware they are fed input data from a datasource which should be agnostic to the cell it's providing data.

If you really need to keep track of your cell population/identity I suggest subclassing `UICollectionViewCell` and adding your own properties to track each cell as required.